# Possible Spam Questions

Tags: discussion, spam

It really looks this question - [Developed an addiction. How can I block websites?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/467585/333666) - is a clever marketing spam post to promote Freedom.to ... it's written in a manner to reject all other reasonable solution already available in macOS / iOS (like screen time) thus inviting "other solutions" where Freedom.to can be promoted. And now SE itself is promoting the question further as a HNQ because of its dramatic copy.

Another similar question is [How can I block the Twitter website on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/454153/333666) which also specifically says it doesn't want to use screen time, thus inviting "other solutions".

(Yes, I know it is hard to judge whether these are indeed spam, as they don't promote the product directly but invite us to innocently suggest it as an answer. I just thought I'd make a note of it here so that we can be aware of the pattern, and keep an eye for it).

Answer (score 2):

Why would a user, who has been on the site for years, provided several questions and answers on various topics and gathered some reputation while doing so, suddenly sit down and carefully craft a question aimed at getting a specific answer mentioning a specific product? A product which has come up a few times already in the past, [both in questions and in answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Freedom)?

I won’t say it’s impossible, but IMHO it seems highly unlikely.

PS: Your second example asks for a solution usable with Apple Configurator. This basically excludes any third-party products.

Comment: When I used to manage communities in Reddit, it was common for old and reputed Reddit accounts to be stolen (hacked) or bought for spam promotion.